# Как рассчитать матрицу через потоки?

Tags: python, многопоточность

```
import threading
import numpy as np

mat1 = np.array([[1, 2 ,1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2]])
mat2 = np.array([[1, 2 ,1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2]])

mat3 = np.array([[2, 2 ,2], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]])
mat4 = np.array([[1, 2 ,3], [3, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]])

def func(m1, m2):
    print(f"{m1.dot(m2)} - [{threading.currentThread().name}]\n")

thr1 = threading.Thread(target=func(mat1, mat2), name="thr-1")
thr1.start()

thr2 = threading.Thread(target=func(mat3, mat4), name="thr-2")
thr2.start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа выполняется в основном потоке, а не в созданных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import threading
import numpy as np

mat1 = np.array([[1, 2 ,1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2]])
mat2 = np.array([[1, 2 ,1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2]])

mat3 = np.array([[2, 2 ,2], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]])
mat4 = np.array([[1, 2 ,3], [3, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]])

def func(m1, m2):
    print(f"{m1.dot(m2)} - [{threading.currentThread().name}]\n")

thr1 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(mat1, mat2), name="поток 1")
thr1.start()

thr2 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(mat3, mat4), name="поток 2")
thr2.start()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
thr1 = threading.Thread(target=func(mat1, mat2), ...
```

Так вы сразу выполняете вызов `func` с аргументами, ещё **до запуска отдельного потока**, а поскольку `func` ничего не возвращает, это получается тоже самое, что такой код:

```
func(mat1, mat2)
thr1 = threading.Thread(target=None, ...
```

Ну а как правильно запускать поток, вы уже и сами поняли. Хотя хорошо бы делать в конце потокам `join`, иначе есть шанс, что они не успеют выполнится до конца основного потока.

```
...
thr1.join()
thr2.join()
```